# DropZone Replace image in init

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

I used this code to upload image from database in init. Now I want when upload a new image to remove this initial image.

```
 var o = $("div#uploader").dropzone({
            url: "../../Merchant/UploadLogo",
            paramName: "logo",
            maxFiles: 1,

            //enqueueForUpload: false,
            maxfilesexceeded: function (file) {
                this.removeAllFiles();
                this.addFile(file);
            },

            addRemoveLinks: true,
            uploadMultiple: false,
            dictRemoveFile: "حذف",

            removedfile: function(file) {
                RemoveFile("Logo");
                var _ref;
                return (_ref = file.previewElement) != null ? _ref.parentNode.removeChild(file.previewElement) : void 0;
            },

            init: function() {

                var mockFile = { name: "avatar1.jpg", size: 12345, type: 'image/jpeg', url: "../../Merchant/GetLogo" };
                this.options.addedfile.call(this, mockFile);
                this.options.thumbnail.call(this, mockFile, mockFile.url);//uploadsfolder is the folder where you have all those uploaded files
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to replace the old image in the `Dropzone` whenever a new Image is successfully uploaded. You can do that by combining the `this.on('success')` and `this.removeFile` methods provided by `Dropzone`:

```
Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
    init: function() {
        this.on('success', function(file, message) {
            if (this.files.length > 1) {
                this.removeFile(this.files[0]);
            }
        });

        // ...
    }
};
```

For this to work, your `mockFile` must also be registered as one of the files of your Dropzone. To do that, you can push it into the `this.files` array in your `init`, right after displaying it:

```
// Create and Display Mock File
var mockFile = { name: "avatar1.jpg", size: 12345, url: '/image.png' };
this.options.addedfile.call(this, mockFile);
this.options.thumbnail.call(this, mockFile, mockFile.url);

// Register it
this.files = [mockFile];
```

---

***Source:***
[Dropzone#SuccessEvent](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#event-success),
[Dropzone#Methods](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#dropzone-methods) and Experience

Comment: Awesome, this does exactly, what limiting the upload to one file via `maxFiles` should do (but doesn't do correctly).